# The type initializer for 'Class' threw an exception

Tags: c#, encryption, console-application, nullreferenceexception

I'm writing a console application as a little tool at work to encrypt/decrypt a number passed in.  The following code is what throws this error:

```
private static readonly string _encryptedKey = 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AffinityEncryptedKey"];

private static readonly string _encryptedInitializationVector = 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AffinityEncryptedInitializationVector"];

private static readonly byte[] _key = Convert.FromBase64String(
    ServiceLocator.Current
        .GetInstance<IEncryptionService>()
        .Decrypt(_encryptedKey));

private static readonly byte[] _initializationVector = Convert.FromBase64String(
    ServiceLocator.Current
        .GetInstance<IEncryptionService>()
        .Decrypt(_encryptedInitializationVector));

static void Main(string[] args)
{ ... }
```

This line: `private static readonly byte[] _key = Convert.FromBase64String(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEncryptionService>().Decrypt(_encryptedKey))` is throwing the error and I'm sure the one after it would bomb too.

The values that I'm retrieving from the app.config file are there and retrieved successfully.  I am referencing the DLL in the project for the IEncryptionService and the ServiceLocator and included it via the using statement.

I checked the InnerException when I debug and it says: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and the source is `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation`.  The problem is that the `Current` property of `ServiceLocator` is null.

I'm not sure how to resolve this.  I copied the code verbatim from elsewhere in another project.  Does anyone know why the `Current` property is null and what can I do to rectify this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 for a halfway reasonable NRE question. Does `ServiceLocator` need to be initialized?

Comment: Took an entirely different approach as I found out it would have been too much of a hassle to use ServiceLocator for what I was doing.  Would have had to register it in a locator, which I don't have set up in my project.  Then, configure it to use a DI container and then configure that container with the IEncryptionService.  In this case, I just instantiated the EncryptionService directly.  Thanks for your response though.